# How we call different function when iframe onload and loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, page-load-time

When we use `onload` method, it will call on loading and after loaded both times the same method. That way can't use for different method calls. How do I call different method by using javascript.

[image: Fronted picture]
[image: Backed picture]

Comment: Can you show how you are adding these events?

Comment: Can you describe what's the expected behavior?

Comment: Hear I wan't finish loading mask when  iframe finished. Can I do that kind of thing. Hear my function will call on loading time and after finished it. So it will finished the loading mask when on loading time. But I want to finished it after loaded the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
public i = 1;

yourLoadFunction() {
  if((this.i%2) == 0) {
    this.loadingMask = false;
    this.i = 1;
  }
  this.i++;
}
```

Comment: Please include details why the code in answer does not work and why this works